# A function that accepts a list of pairs and adds new pairs that are the averages of the neighbouring pair values

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

Probably a duplicate, but it isn't easy browsing through list-related questions.

I am looking for an elegant way to construct a function that accepts a list of pairs, for example

```
list1 = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
```

and returns a list with added elements that are arithmetic means of the neighbouring coordinates.

```
list2 = Function[list1] = {{x1, y1}, {(x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2}, {x2, y2},
{(x2+x3)/2, (y2+y3)/2}, {x3, y3}};
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up `MovingAverage` and `Riffle`.

Comment: Amplifying on comment by @Szabolcs: `MovingAverage[Riffle[list1,list1],2]`

Comment: Yet another method:  `Most[Riffle[#, (# + RotateLeft[#])/2]]&`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the lists of consecutive pairs with [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html):

```
list1 = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
pairs = Partition[list1, 2, 1]
```

The easiest way to construct your desired output from here is to compute the means on these and then [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) them back into the original list:

```
Riffle[list1, Mean /@ pairs]
(* {{x1, y1}, {(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2}, {x2, y2}, 
    {(x2 + x3)/2, (y2 + y3)/2}, {x3, y3}}
```

`Partition` and `Map` (abbreviated as `/@` above) can also be combined into one step with [`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
Riffle[list1, BlockMap[Mean, list1, 2, 1]]
```

However, as Szabolcs points out in a comment, for the specific case where the function you want to apply is `Mean`, you can skip `Partitions` (or `BlockMap`) altogether and use [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html) instead:

```
Riffle[list1, MovingAverage[pairs, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

using `Replace` and recursion

```
list1 = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};

Clear@func;
func[list_] := list /. {___, a : {_, _}, b : {_, _}, d : {_, _} ...} :> 
Join[{a, Mean[{a, b}]}, func[Join[{b}, {d}]]] 

func[list1];

(* {{x1, y1}, {(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2}, {x2, y2}, {(x2 + x3)/2, 
(y2 + y3)/2}, {x3, y3}} *)
```

yet another way using `ReplaceRepeated`

```
list1 //. {p___, a : {__Symbol}, b : {__Symbol},c : {__Symbol} ...} :>
{p, a, Mean[{a, b}], b, c}

(* {{x1, y1}, {(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2}, {x2, y2}, {(x2 + x3)/2, (
y2 + y3)/2}, {x3, y3}} *)
```

similar to @Martin Ender but **without** `Riffle`

```
Clear@func;
func[list_] := 
Flatten[#, 1] &@Join[BlockMap[Through[{First, Mean}[#]] &, list, 2, 
 1], {{Last@list}}];

func[list1]

(* {{x1, y1}, {(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2}, {x2, y2}, {(x2 + x3)/2, 
(y2 + y3)/2}, {x3, y3}} *)
```

@Szabolcs and @Bob Hanlon's method (fewer lines, easy to understand, more elegant):

```
MovingAverage[Riffle[list1, list1], 2]
```

Comment: @drabus you can see the above mentioned implementations too. there are a lot of ways things can be done in Mathematica

Comment: In your `func` solution, you use three dots in your rule. What do those three dots mean?. I tried searching for it, but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: @AnjanKumar its known as `RepeatedNull`. It accounts for the null case i.e. when nothing exists.

Comment: @AnjanKumar it takes care of cases when the length of the list is odd. For even length of the list you can use `Repeated` rather than `RepeatedNull`. This is true for this particular case !

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Anjan you are welcome !

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
```

Using `SequenceCases` (new in 10.1)

```
Append[Last @ list] @ SequenceCases[list, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :>
   Sequence[{a, b}, {(a + c)/2, (b + d)/2}], Overlaps -> True]
```

{{x1, y1}, {(x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2}, {x2, y2}, {(x2 + x3)/2, (y2 + y3)/2}, {x3, y3}}